# Using Qt Installer Framework to create my Application Installer

Tags: qt, package, qt-installer

I want to create an installer for my Application. So, I have read about Qt Installer Framework and I tested the tutorial example and create the installer and everything work find with the example. But I have a doubt when I try to do the same process for my Application. When I compile the code a folder is created at the same level of my code:

- MyApplication (my code)
- build-MyApplication-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Release (code compiled)

So my questions are:

What files of the compilation do I need to copy into the folder `myinstaller/packages/vendor/` recommended by Qt Intaller Framework?

If I have dependencies of Qt like serialport, multimedia, and others, how do I insert these dependecies with Qt Installer Framework?

Comment: This is all covered in the Qt documentation on Windows deployment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: @MrEricSir, I had read the doc about deployment but they don't explain or  I don't understand how do I create an installer for my application. I have a shadow build folder and I am using QtCreator. If you have a little example of how to do that, please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`windeployqt.exe` is what you want.  Just run that on the command line and give it your executable as the argument.  It will automatically copy in all the required Qt libraries and even provide the runtime redistributable installer.  Then you can use the binarycreator to generate an installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the dependencies in myinstaller/packages/vendor/data, along with your exe. and eventual additional files. I recommended using i.e. dependency walker for finding all the required dependencies. Some of the binarycreator tutorials on qt are outdated; make sure you use the command

```
<location-of-ifw>\binarycreator.exe -t <location-of-ifw>\installerbase.exe -p <package_directory> -c <config_directory>\<config_file> <installer_name>
```

with the appropriate arguments.